# OpenDNS Crypt client always ask to run on startup?

Tags: windows-8, boot, opendns

I used to use OpenDNS Crypt in windows 7 64 bit without issues,but when i upgrade to windows 8 64-bit,
this program ask me to run every time i start my pc (UAC message popup)...so is this any way to make this program run silently on startup without any messages?

Comment: Try reinstalling it (and "Run as administrator").

Comment: Thank you,i tried but the UAC message still popup when i enter to desktop...is there any another suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

It appears this is a known problem with OpenDNS, and they are busy working on a solution.  From [this thread](https://forums.opendns.com/comments.php?DiscussionID=16499):

> Our engineers are aware of the behavior regarding the User Access
>   Control (UAC) and hope to have it resolved in future releases. Thanks
>   for your patience while we continue to improve this service.

Answer (score 0):

When you [run it as a service](https://github.com/jedisct1/dnscrypt-proxy/blob/master/README-WINDOWS.markdown), which acts as a proxy, it does not request privilege elevation. In fact, this is the current method recommended by OpenDNS. The easy(ier) installation method runs an outdated version of DNScrypt.